# Does the select function change the value of the second argument readfds sometimes

Tags: linux, sockets, select, sleep

This is the code:

```
FD_ZERO(&t_set);
num = 0;
maxfd = 0;

while (num < MAX)
{
    if ((sockfd = connectSocket(ptr)))
        ;
    //printf("connect to server succeed!\n%d\n", fd);
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "connect error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!writeSocket(sockfd, ptr))
        ;
        //printf("write to server succeed!\n");
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (maxfd < sockfd)
        maxfd = sockfd;
    FD_SET(sockfd, &t_set);
    printf("%d\n", t_set);
    memset(fileName, 0, BUFSIZE);
    sprintf(fileName,"%d.html", sockfd);
    if ((filefd = open(fileName, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH)) == -1)
    {
        printf("create file failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ff[num].sockfd = sockfd;
    ff[num].filefd = filefd;
    ++num;
}
printf(">------------------->\n");  
while (1) 
{
    //sleep(1);
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    h = 0;
    printf("%d\n", t_set);           //print the t_set before select
    h = select(maxfd + 1, &t_set, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    printf("%d\n", t_set);           //print the t_set after select
    printf(">------------------->\n");  
    //fd_set is an array of long;
    //if use printf("%d %d", t_set, h); secondly may print the second value of t_set , not h;
    if (h < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "select error");
        return -1;
    }
    if (h == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "select return 0\n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (!FD_ISSET(ff[n].sockfd, &t_set))
            ++n;
        if (readSocket(ff[n].sockfd, ff[n].filefd))
        {
            FD_CLR(ff[n].sockfd, &t_set);
            printf("===================== %d\n", n);
        }
    }

}

num = 0;
while (num++ < MAX)
    close(ff[num].filefd);
```

The output:

```
8           // initial of t_set
40
168
680
2728
>------------------->
2728       // the two value were print before and after the select;
680
>------------------->
680
680
>------------------->
680
680
>------------------->
680
680
```

Printing the value of t_set, I found the value of t_set was changed after calling select at the first and the last loop.
If add sleep(1) before select and set tv_set.sec = 0, tv_usec = 0, using sleep timeout replace select timeout, the t_set perform normal. 
There is another problem, the above example can't monitor the last socket, using the sleep change can also repair the problem;

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the select(2) man page:

"On exit, the sets [that is, `readfs`, `writefds`, and `exceptfds`] are modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed status."

You are only using `readfs`, but it is *supposed* to be modified by the `select` system call.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem that I have struggled so long; I  knew the select will modify the timeout argument, but I think select will reset the readfds and monitor the specified bits.readfds argument should reset every loop;

Comment: You answer light me;I consider my logic of the program, all the problems solved!Thank you again!